# Is there a way to retrieve the inner types of a type using variadic templates in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, using

Assume I have a type using variadic templates:

```
template <typename... Args>
struct Outer
{
  // using Inner = something that captures ...Args ???;
}
```

How could I define `Inner` such that I could later use it elsewhere in some templated code like:

```
// ... some existing function accepting potentially other template arguments
template <typename... Args2>
foo(Args2 ...)
{
 // ...
};
// ... somewhere I define some specialized Outers, as examples but not limited to
using Specific1 = Outer<int, double, bool>;
using Specific2 = Outer<std::string>;
// ...
foo(Specific1::Inner... args)
// ...
foo(Specific2::Inner... args)
```

I am mainly interested on C++17, but open to learn however it could be done in any other version of C++. Ideally I would like to achieve this without joggling around with `std::tuple`.

A minimal reproducible example:

```
template <typename... Args>
struct Outer
{
    using Cb = std::function<void(Args...)>;

    //using Inner = Args; // this one complains "parameter pack must be expanded in this context"
    //using Inner = Args...; // this one complains "parameter pack cannot be expanded in this context"

    template<typename CbIn>
    void store(CbIn&& cb)
    {
        mCb = std::forward<CbIn>(cb);
    }

    void call(Args... args) noexcept
    {
        mCb(args...);
    }

    // cb here accepts Args... and returns OtherOuter* (specialized with different Args)
    template<typename OtherOuter, typename CbIn>
    void foo(CbIn&& cb)
    {
        store([cb{ std::forward<CbIn>(cb)}](Args... args)
        {
            OtherOuter * other = cb(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            other->store([](/*OtherOuter::Inner*/ ... otherArgs) // what to put here if not OtherOuter::Inner ???
            {
                // do something with otherArgs
                ([&]
                {
                    std::cout << "second " << otherArgs << std::endl;
                } (), ...);
            });
            std::cout << "first " << other->mFlag << std::endl;
        });
    }

    Cb mCb;
    bool mFlag = false;
};
```

And using the example:

```
using OuterIntBool = Outer<int, bool>;
using OuterString = Outer<std::string>;
// works
{
    OuterIntBool outerIntBool;
    outerIntBool.store([](int i, bool b)
    {
        bool isValid = i > 0 && b;
        assert(isValid);
    });
    outerIntBool.call(1, true);
}
// does not work
{
    OuterIntBool outerIntBool;
    OuterString otherString;
    outerIntBool.foo<OuterString>([&otherString](int/* i*/, bool b)
    {
        otherString.mFlag = b;
        return &otherString;
    });
    outerIntBool.call(1, true);
    otherString.call("bar");
}
```

Comment: What should Inner be? What are inner types? You have never explained this.

Comment: - What should Inner be?
That is actually the question
- What are inner types?
They could be whatever, since those are variadic template arguments. The `using Specific = Outer<int, double, bool>;` is just an example, the inner types in this specific example are `<int, double, bool>`.

Comment: Are you looking for `std::tuple`?

Comment: No, but good point, I need an answer that does not use `std::tuple`. A lot of people are drawn to throw `std::tuple` around in stackoverflow.

Comment: It looks like XY problem. What is your root task?

Comment: Explaining the root task would involve 1k lines of code. I boiled down the question to its minimum expression. Not really interested in workarounds but what is explicitly asked here: How can I retrieve the inner types of a template type using variadic templates?

Comment: You can use `std::tuple`. `Specific::Inner ... args` is a syntactically invalid construct w/o `template`. You can use `[](Specific::Inner args)` with `using Inner = std::tuple<Args...>`.

Comment: What if I want to pass around those `Specific::Inner ... args` to another template function which accepts potentially different variadic template arguments? E.g. `template <typename... Args2> foo(Args2 ...)`? I am not sure there would be an implicit conversion between `std::tuple<Args...>` and `Args2 ...`.

Comment: `Specific1::Inner` looks ok, its just missing a `typename`. Your code is too pseudo to see the actual issue you are having. Please post a [mcve]

Comment: a [mcve] is not 1k lines of code. You do not need 1k lines of code to write a small example like you just posted. However, the example should not contain a wall of unrelated errors. It should illustrate the one issue your question is about

Comment: Added minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `other->store([](auto&& ... otherArgs)`?

Answer (score 3):

> How to "save" variadic template parameter?

The direct way, as we do with regular template argument is **not** possible:

```
template <typename T>
struct s1
{
    using type = T; // OK
};

template <typename... Ts>
struct s2
{
    using types = Ts...; // KO
};
```

but, they are several ways to "save" variadic arguments:

- Use some variadic type to keep it `std::tuple` or your own type_list

  ```
  template <typename... Ts> struct type_list {};

  template <typename... Args>
  struct Outer
  {
      using type1s = std::tuple<Args...>;
      using type2s = type_list<Args...>;
  };
  ```
- A destructured way:

  ```
  template <typename... Args>
  struct Outer
  {
      constexpr type_size = sizeof...(Args);
      template <std::size_t I>
      using type = std::tuple_element_t<I, std::tuple<Args...>>;
  };
  ```
- an external type_trait (with any of the above result). so destructured way example:

  ```
  template <typename T>
  constexpr std::size_t outer_size;

  template <typename... Ts>
  constexpr std::size_t outer_size<Outer<Ts...>> = sizeof...(Ts);

  template <std::size_t I, typename T>
  struct arg_element;

  template <std::size_t I, typename... Ts>
  struct arg_element<I, Outer<Ts...>> {
      using type = std::tuple_element_t<Is, std::tuple<Ts...>>;
  };
  ```

> How to use saved parameters?

`std::index_sequence` might help:

```
template <typename Outer>
void get_printer(const Outer&)
{
    []<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>){
        // typename Outer::template type<Is>... is not equivalent to the Ts...
        // std::tuple_element_t<Is, typename Outer::types>... for tuple case

        return [](const typename Outer::template type<Is>&... args){
            (std::cout << args), ...);
        };
    }(std::make_index_sequence<Outer::size_type>()); // tuple_size<Outer::types>


}
```